# Insert into free id MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to be able to safely insert a row with first available ID. I read alot answers about PRIMARY_KEY and AUTO_INCREMENT and all this stuff, but this is something else. I need to keep and be able to work on database with fixed ID range from 1 to 60000. Is there any way to do that with MySQL? Writing own function that check what is nearest "free" ID, is not an option cause there may be conflicts on multiuser usage.

In the best case scenario,MySQL would somehow work as with PRIMARY_KEY, but reusing keys.

Comment: what happens when you hit the 60,000th key? And why such an arbitrary limit?

Comment: Just create a table (with a last_modified timestamp). Insert 60000 rows. And update the oldest one.

Comment: If there are 60000 records already, another one is not being added. Why would I update oldest one? I need to be able to insert / remove / modify records. Not only insert them...

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

**1) Create a sequence table with columns `id, rowstate`.**

**2) Insert ids `1-60000` to that with the rowstate 1**

**3) Whenever you want to insert in your main table, search for the lowest id from the sequence table having rowstate=1 and update the sequence to -1. 
When you want to delete a record from the main table, set the rowstate of the id to 1.**

Comment: And what when 2 people would act on same record at same time?

Comment: use transactions and locks. you can `select for transaction` lock a record, so that no other paralle processes can access that record.

Answer (score 1):

you are write, you need to concider the the concurrency issues
hence you need to implement a table lock mechnism

1) [Lock mysql table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)

2) Insert the record, you can just use the auto_increment property since no two values would be added at the same time (i dont think you have to lock tables if this is used anyway)

3) If you dont want to use auto_increment, any of the above suggested code will work

Comment: What happens when user tries to act on locked table? What happens when user gets disconnected before table unlock?

Comment: 1) other user will get an error saying he cant access the table now, a proper code will handle this error and either retry or ask the user to retry [keep in mind that this happening is realy rare]

2) when a connection dies, the locks are released, no need to worry about that, unless you are handling the locks manually using your own table lock mechanism

Comment: Is there any way to make it queue handled by MySQL?

Comment: i believe yes, refer the [Delayed Insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html)

Comment: WOW that is so cool, it may work. Could you edit your answer so it would contain `INSERT DELAYED` information? I will probably accept this answer, will have to check first if it really works though.

Comment: but i still believe that a well written code is better, since most of the popular frameworks even wont go for Delay Insert function [it takes more server overhead as per the documentation]

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=(Select max(id)+1 from tableName);
```

For more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

**OR**

Getting highest id from table and increament it and insert your row.

```
Select max(id) from tableName;
```

You will get the id. Than add 1 it and insert into table. Additionally you can check it should be less than 60000.

I know this is not the best answer, but can be consider as second alternative.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first `id` that is free you can do

```
select id - (id-ra) as lowest
from
(
  select id, @r := @r + 1 as ra
  from t, (select @r := 0) rank
  order by id
)
x 
where ra <> id
limit 1
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da533/4)

You can put that in a procedure where you [lock the table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html) during the operation

```
delimiter |
CREATE PROCEDURE create_save ()
BEGIN     

    LOCK TABLES your_table WRITE;

    set @lowid := 0;
    select @lowid := id - (id-ra)
    from
    (
      select id, @r := @r + 1 as ra
      from your_table, (select @r := 0) rank
      order by id
    )
    x 
    where ra <> id
    limit 1;

    if @lowid between 1 and 59999
    then
        insert into your_table (id, othercolumn)
        select @lowid, 12345;
    end if;

    UNLOCK TABLES;

end
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Still it has concurrency issues.

Comment: You could lock the table.